# "study a book" VS "study out of(from) a book"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

I'm not sure if '***study a book***' is a correct phrasing. "**Study out of a book**" or "**study from a book**" looks more correct to me, and they mean *to learn from a book*.

Will "**study a book**" mean the same thing if it's a correct phrase? Are there any differences among those phrases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are *studying* about the book.  As a different example: if you *study* a painting, you not only examine all the aspects of the image portrayed but possibly also the brushwork, the framing, the presentation, and other elements.

In the same way, if you *study* a book, you might examine the binding, the print, the paper, the cover, and all the other elements that make up a book.

(As a side note, this particular academic field is called [*Philology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philology).  A *philologist* will study not only the text of any written document, but all the materials of its construction, as well as the cultural and historical factors that may have influenced its publication.)

On the other hand, if you are instead reading the text of a book in order to learn its contents (such as for school), then you are correct, and *study from a book* sounds more appropriate.

That being said, I would not use any of these.  I study *some material* for *some purpose*, e.g.

> I'm going to the library to study **chemistry** for **my midterm exam next week**.

Otherwise I would simply *read*, or *learn from* something like a textbook, not *study* it.